# Classic Vs YAML Pipeline - Approval & Gates / Checks in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

We are using classic pipelines currently for Release through Azure Devops.

We are looking to move this to multi stage YAML as it will be easier to manager a standard template and track changes better.

As per our analysis, most of the features of classic pipelines are supported in YAML.

But, there is no clear cut information for "Approval and Gates".

Referring to this article it talks about gates but seems more from context of Releases that are supported in classic not yaml

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/?view=azure-devops

We need confirmation or clarity on points below -

- post-approvals can not be supported in YAML as interface it supports only pre-approval
- For YAML through environment we can add checks but to what extent can they be used in same way as gates we are not sure
- can we set revaluation, time outs etc in same way as gates. If yes, then how ?
- Service now integration does it work same way in YAML or any caveats
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/servicenow?view=azure-devops

If someone can help clarify our doubts it will help

Comment: You can answer all of this yourself by making a YAML pipeline and playing with the features for a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Pipelines as a code(YAML file) make it easier to manage your pipelines & track changes for sure. I can't give you confirmation on all your points but I did the same kind of migration (classic pipeline --> pipeline as a code) a year ago, and from my experience, the YAML files will just create pipelines on Azure DevOps like the classic pipelines. You'll be able to set policies(approvals, checks, gates, etc) on these like the classic pipelines through Azure DevOps and you might be able to set some policies in yaml file directly.

Comment: I disagree partially. Classic release still has some advantages over yaml pipelines. Not sure why they aren't integrated to the yaml pipeline as it's been many years like that.

Classic release allows you to set approbation based on the pipeline itself and not the related environment. This allows for more flexibility when an environment is used by different releases.

Also, with classic release you can approve a pipeline and defer execution to a later time, which you can't in yaml pipelines.

You can also disable on the fly steps inside a release. It is much more flexible IMO.